# "On se rappelle" et "on rappelle"

Tags: sens, verbes-pronominaux

> On rappelle que par convention, les échanges sont comptés positivement lorsque le système reçoit et négativement lorsqu'il donne.
>
> On se rappelle que par convention, les échanges sont comptés positivement lorsque le système reçoit et négativement lorsqu'il donne.

Dans un ouvrage j'ai rencontré la première variante. Quelle est la différence avec la seconde variante qui emploie la forme pronominale (se rappeler) ?

Comment: Dans "On rappelle que [...]", le sujet est l'auteur ("on" pour "nous", pour "je"). Dans "On se rappellera que [...]", le sujet est le lecteur ("on" indéfini).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Succintement:

1. On rappelle que: c'est au sens de: *notons que*, ou encore *remind* en anglais
2. On se rappelle:  c'est au sens de: *on se souvient* / *on sait que*, ou encore *remember* en anglais

Answer (score 3):

La première rafraîchit la mémoire du lecteur/de l'auditoire si besoin est, ***on*** représente la personne qui s'exprime. C'est aussi une manière polie de donner une nouvelle information.

La deuxième indique au lecteur qu'il est supposé ne pas avoir oublié cette information. ***On*** inclus l'auditoire ou les lecteurs.